# Default parameter for methods in routing type resource Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, routeparams

I'm trying to add default parameter to resource routing as per documentation:

[image: Laravel doc]

My code looks like:

```
Route::resource('flats', FlatsController::class)->parameters([
    'index' => 'test_parameter',
    'create' => 'test_parameter1',
    'update' => 'test_parameter2'
]);
```

But unfortunately all the time when listing the routing it gets like in the screenshot below:

[image: routing list]

Please help guide at what point do I make a mistake?

Comment: its correct.if you dd($request->all()) then you get these default params.

Comment: parameters will Override the route parameter names.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're trying to override route segments or actions but not route parameters. Route parameters are those in curly braces.

Comment: @shaedrich I know what you mean, but my goal is to add a parameter to the index function, for example, so that calling it looks like index/{parameter}. I found solution on laracast: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/routeresource-parameters but it's not working

Comment: So which route doesn't have the `{flat}` parameter? Did you forget to mention it in your picture?

Comment: @shaedrich now I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. I would like to add an extra parameter for the index function in resource routing. That's all. The way I want to add an additional parameter is not visible in the list at all, which is visible in the picture I sent

Comment: See my answer below ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following:

```markdown
| Methods   | route                               |
|-----------|-------------------------------------|
| POST      | panel/investments/flats             |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats             |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats/create      |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats/{flat}      |
| PUT/PATCH | panel/investments/flats/{flat}      |
| DELETE    | panel/investments/flats/{flat}      |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats/{flat}/edit |
```

Since the only parameter is `{flat}` you can only rename this one as [per docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters):

```
Route::resource('flats', FlatsController::class)->parameters([
    'flat' => 'apartment'
]);
```

This results in:

```markdown
| Methods   | route                                    |
|-----------|------------------------------------------|
| POST      | panel/investments/flats                  |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats                  |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats/create           |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats/{apartment}      |
| PUT/PATCH | panel/investments/flats/{apartment}      |
| DELETE    | panel/investments/flats/{apartment}      |
| GET/HEAD  | panel/investments/flats/{apartment}/edit |
```

Comment: So i can't add additional parameter into resource routing like this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/routeresource-parameters ?

Comment: Adding additional parameters and overriding existing one's are two very different animals – so as far as I know, no.